# $in scans more documents compared to find command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using explain to check the mongodb stat . I am querying on the indexed field source .

`db.order.find({"source":"x"})` explain stat gives it is scanning 2k+ documents.

`db.order.find({"source":"y"})` explain stat gives it is scanning 6k+ documents.

`db.order.find({"source":{$in:["x","y"]}})` explain stat gives it is scanning more than 100000 documents.

I am not sure why `$in` query is scanning so many documents . I have gone through many links over StackOverflow which says `$in` also utilizes the indexing of the field. Please help me to understand why the document scan is very high in case of `$in` query.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the actual explain output?

Comment: in the explain, what does the winning plan say for each?  i think that will give you insight on what's going on.